# How to change white background of an gif image to transparent

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gif

I have an gif Image like example

[image: Gif Image]

and I want to make its background transparent from white.
I am an learner of Photoshop so please describe steps to do it.
Currently I was trying to edit each and every layer of this image but its really tough to go through all the layers and I am sure there is an easier way for it

Comment: If you don't want to use photoshop, try unscreen.com, an AI tool that can remove backgrounds from gifs and videos. [Source](https://codegena.com/remove-video-background-online-without-green-screen/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to automatically do all the layers at once, but you can certainly speed things up by creating an action to do one layer.

All the layers in that image (bar the first one) are invisible by default, so start out with an invisible layer selected.

Create a new action and record the following steps:

- Make the layer visible
- Select -> Colour Range...
- Choose white and a fuzziness of around 45
- Hit backspace to delete the selection
- Deselect the area - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>
- Hide the layer again

Then you'll have an action that looks like this:

[image: Actions pallette]

Now you still have to stitch through the 80 layers but for each one you just have to play your action.

Comment: Add a select forward layer (alt+[) to the last action makes it easier to cycle, anyway Photoshop is the wrong tool for this job, use AE.

Comment: @joojaa, ah great tip! I couldn't work out how to make it switch to the next layer. Never used After Effects, so sadly can't advise.

Comment: @joojaa-Please describe how to do that using AE.

Comment: @OGHaza-Thanks a Lot it saved a Lot of time and effort..

Comment: What I did was created an action then looped it 10 times in another so one single click does for 10 layers.

Comment: @user, ah nice yeah good thinking, glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late, but if you are using Windows, here's another way:

1. Download [ScreenToGif](https://www.screentogif.com).
2. Load your gif via File > Load.
3. Click to save in File > Save as.
4. Under Gif options, enable transparency.
5. Select the color to be treated as transparent via a color picker.
6. Save.

[image: ScreenToGif]

(PS: I'm the developer)

Comment: This is an awesome app. Great job.

Answer (score -3):

Use Magic Eraser tool for each layer...That will definitely speed up things